# Meta Tags dont show

Tags: wordpress

I'm having an issue with my meta tags. They wont work for my `title` `description` and `keywords` when I add the meta tags as such:

```
<title>Website Title </title>
<meta name="Description" content="Content Descriptoion">
<meta name="Keywords" content="Keywords">
```

Nothing shows when checked, I also add `<HEAD> </head>` but no luck.

I added these codes to the header, theme and index.

If I add just the keywords though they show or if I just add the meta description it shows as well but not all the description it only shows 3 words of it.

Comment: Could adding a closing `/` make the difference? Probably not, but its good practise: `<meta name="keywords" content="Keywords" />`. Also, the names are lowercase!

Comment: the keywords when placed alone works but it doesnt work as a unit

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "It doesn't work as a unit"?

Comment: if i add all the meta tags at once in order showed above

Comment: So if you add 1 it works but when you add 3 it doesn't? Also, when you use `Inspect Element` and dig into the pages DOM tree, are they in the `<head>` tag or are you inserting them into an `<header>`?

Comment: if i add the keywords alone they work but for title and description they dont work i add them in my header.php on the top

Comment: ive also added them into the `<head>` tag but they dont work either

Comment: What is defined as 'not working'? Did you add them between a `<?php` and `?>` tag (that would be a problem)? Otherwise they should just show up.

Comment: i added a `<html>` tag with the `<head>` tag and managed to get the title and keywords working but the meta description doesnt show all the description just 3 words of it

Comment: Where are you seeing this? If this is wordpress you shouldn't _have to do this yourself_. It would surprise me enormously if Wordpress does not support those basic, 30-year old metatags...

Comment: im using http://www.metachecker.net/ to check my meta tags i add them in the header manually in wordpress